# What does the traditional "Three Days" mean to Loonies?

Tags: the-cat-who-walks-through-walls

In the book "The Cat Who Walks Through Walls" , Dr. Richard Ames in conversation with Rabbi Ezra '*claims Three Days*' on being informed that he was wanted for murder. Rabbi was trying to get hired as Ames' attorney instead of claiming the ransom.

p. 192 1st edition 1985

Answer (score 5):

Based on context, and that later Rabbi Ezra mentions it in context of Ames asking if Ezra said anything to a visitor, it sounds like there is a tradition where you can ask someone for a period of time before they go to the authorities.

> "Rabbi, I don't think you would anyhow; you're too much the old Loonie.
> You're simply trying to chivvy me into hiring you. Mmm. I claim the Three
> Days."

....

> "Interesting. Did you send him to ask me who was
> offering a reward for you and the amount of the reward?" "I certainly did
> not! Did you tell him anything?" "My dear sir! You asked for the
> traditional Three Days."

My text search of the book doesn't bring up any other cases where it's capitalized like that, so I don't think there really is a further explanation. It's just a plot device.

Comment: I had just gotten to that paragraph .

Comment: I'm thinking it must be some tradition going back to before revolution times.

Comment: @Stevko Since we're referring to "Loonies" here, it's possible the answer will be found in _The Moon is a Harsh Mistress_.

Comment: @Spencer: Good idea, but I'm coming up with nothing on my search on the text.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible that it is a reference to Jesus having risen from the dead on the third day.

Comment: Perhaps, but there's also the Islamic tradition of 3 days of hospitality: https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/45538